# Angular2. Checkif a Json Key has content

Tags: angular, typescript

on the following Json, I receive different products to show on screen. Please notice "Medical250" has values, but "hospital", "life" and "dental" doesnt. This happens depending on the state I send to the API feed (and age).

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "quotekey": "1e2532897f24a46b98799665e43052423",
    "membership": [{
            "planid": "1",
            "membership": "Select Basic",
            "fee": "10.95"
        },
        {
            "planid": "2",
            "membership": "Select Silver",
            "fee": "19.95"
        },
        {
            "planid": "3",
            "membership": "Select Gold",
            "fee": "29.95"
        },
        {
            "planid": "4",
            "membership": "Select Platinum",
            "fee": "39.95"
        },
        {
            "planid": "5",
            "membership": "Select Diamond",
            "fee": "49.95"
        }
    ],
    "dental": [],
    "medical0": [],
    "medical250": [{
            "plannumber": "1",
            "single": "9.49",
            "couple": "18.97",
            "singlewithdependents": "21.82",
            "family": "26.56"
        },
        {
            "plannumber": "2",
            "single": "12.28",
            "couple": "24.55",
            "singlewithdependents": "28.23",
            "family": "34.37"
        },
        {
            "plannumber": "3",
            "single": "14.07",
            "couple": "28.14",
            "singlewithdependents": "32.36",
            "family": "39.40"
        },
        {
            "plannumber": "4",
            "single": "16.74",
            "couple": "33.48",
            "singlewithdependents": "38.50",
            "family": "46.87"
        }
    ],
    "hospital": [],
    "life": []
}
```

Im parsing that Json and getting the values as follows:

```
this.MedicalQuote = this.APIresult[0].medical250[0].single;
```

etc... but when I try to get this.APIresult[0].dental[0].single; which doesnt exist, my code crashes. Is there a way to identify if a key, like "dental" in this case, contains any value or if it just empty []? All keys have a value called "single", except for "membership" which will always contain values.

I am now doing try - catch (e) for each product but it doesnt look like a clean solution, I would like to do it the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: Before this line `this.APIresult[0].medical250[0].single`, you need a check for medical250 exists or not `if(this.APIresult[0].medical250 && this.APIresult[0].medical250.length > 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an "if" statement to check if the property exists, for example:

```
if(thisSession.hasOwnProperty('dental')){
    //your code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `?` sign after properties which can be empty and it'll return undefined.

`const result = this.APIresult[0].dental[0]?.single`

Then the `result` variable will be undefined and you can work with it as you need.

Comment: Hi Igor. Im getting "undefined" whether dental has values or not.